# verifying email address and the number of periods in the address

Tags: c++

Im trying to learn c++ in my spare time and needed a little guidance.  Im trying to ask a user to input a file which contains a list of email addresses.  From that list i want to check each email address to say that that each address contains exactly 1 period. And i want to solve this using a bool that includes a pointer.  Im having trouble on how to start the function. I was successful inputting the file but im lost on my next move.  Any help is appreciated. thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <cstdlib>  
#include <cstring>  
using namespace std;


bool oneAt(const char *email);
bool nonblankAt(const char *email);
bool oneDot(const char *email);
bool nonblankDot(const char *email);

int main(){
    char filename[25];
    ifstream fin;

    cout << "Enter the input file\n";
    cin >> filename;

    fin.open(filename);
    if(fin.fail()){
        cerr << "Input file opening error.\n";
    }
    else{
        cout << "success\n";
    }
    const int size = 50;
    char line[size];





    fin.close();
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
bool oneAt(const char *email)
```

Comment: First, know that a valid e-mail address can contain more than one period. Now, if this simply an exercise for you, that's fine. To answer your question, one approach is to iterate over every character per line and keep track of the number of periods you encounter. If the count is not equal to exactly 1, then your function can return false.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn C++, prefer `std::string` over character arrays and pointers:

```
bool oneAt(const std::string& email)
{
    return email.find('@') != email.end();
}

int main()
{
    std::string filename;

    cout << "Enter the input file\n";
    if (std::cin >> filename)
    {
        if (std::ifstream fin(filename))
        {
            std::string line;
            while (getline(std::cin, line))
            {
                 if (oneAt(line))
                     std::cout << "found one @ in '" << line << "'\n";
                 // similar for checking for periods etc..
            }
        }
        else
            std::cerr << "Input file opening error.\n";
    }
    else
        cerr << "Error reading filename\n";
}
```

That said, any vaguely serious (usable for real) effort to validate an email address is better done with a regular expression or custom parser, and it notoriously complicated.  Google "regular expression for email validation" or similar and you'll find raging discussions and lots of variations at different levels of sophistication.  I doubt anyone knows which is "best" in terms of most accurate overall coverage.